# list of objects containing lists of objects

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a list of objects (Elements), where each element contains a list of objects (GaussPoints). The number of GaussPoints per Element can be variable, although in the example below each element has only one GaussPoint for simplicity.

```
class Element:
    gp = []

class GaussPoint:
    argument = 0


k = 0
elements = []
for ele in xrange(4):
    k = k+1
    anEle = Element()

    aGP = GaussPoint()
    aGP.argument = k
    print k

    elements.append(anEle)

    elements[ele].gp.append(aGP)

print "testing the data structure:"
for ele in xrange(4):
    print elements[ele].gp[0].argument
```

The output is:

```
1
2
3
4
testing the data structure:
1
1
1
1
```

What I'm expecting would be:

```
1
2
3
4
testing the data structure:
1
2
3
4
```

Somehow the code doesn't create a new list of GaussPoints for each Element, but appends to the same one.

I'm obviously misunderstanding something quite fundamental about Python. Could anyone please help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make `Element.gp` an instance variable, like so:

```
class Element:
    def __init__(self):
        self.gp = []
```

Currently, `gp` is a member of the *class itself* and is in effect shared by all instances of the class. You change it in one, and it appears to change in all.

It is arguably good style to make the same change to `GaussPoint.argument`:

```
class GaussPoint:
    def __init__(self):
        self.argument = 0
```

Finally, I'd recommend reading the [tutorial on classes](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#classes).

Comment: thanks, you pointed me in the right direction. the problem is with the list "gp" though:`class Element:
    def __init__(self):
        self.gp = []`

Answer (score 2):

You're initializing `Element.gp` as a class variable, rather than an instance variable, so it's shared across all your `Element` objects. You end up with 1 `gp` being an array of length 4, rather than 4 `gp`s of length 1.

Instead, initialize it in an `__init__` method like so:

```
class Element:
    def __init__(self):
        self.gp = []
```

You're making `argument` a class variable, but since you reassign it for each instance, rather than modify it as you do `element`, it ends up holding the value you'd expect.